# Set theory difficult question on proving that set $\mathbf {H}$ always exists

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have been puzzling over this question for literally hours:

> Let H be a 1011-element subset of the set {0, 1, 2, ..., 2021}. Prove that it has two (not necessarily distinct) elements a and b such that a+b is a power of 2.

After watching a heap of Youtube videos about set theory, I have finally come up with this:
$$\mathbf {H} \subset \mathbb {N} | \mathbf {H} _ z = m, m \in \mathbb {N}, 0 \leq m \leq 2021, |\mathbf {H}| = 1011 \\
\mathbf {J} = \{(a, b) | a + b = 2 ^ {n} | n \in \mathbb {N}\} \\
(\mathbf {H} _ x, \mathbf {H} _ y) \in \mathbf {J} | x \in \mathbb {N}, y \in \mathbb {N}, x \neq y$$

However, since I am very inexperienced, I can't solve this...
I would really appreciate a solution and an explanation on how you have got to that answer :)

Comment: Pigeonhole principle with holes $\{2021,27\},\{2020,28\},\{2019,29\},\dots,\{26,6\},\{25,7\},\{24,8\},\dots,\{5,3\},\{0,4\},\{2\},\{1\}$.  If you have two pigeons in one of the first set of holes, those pigeons necessarily add up to $2048 = 2^{11}$, else in the next set of holes add up to $32 = 2^5$, or add up to $8,4,2,$ or $1$

Comment: yes @JMoravitz you are right thanks a bunch! :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I claim that we can pair up the numbers $0,\ldots,2021$ into $1010$ pairs so that the sum of each pair is a power of $2$, or at least one element of the pair is a power of $2$.

Note that we can start by pairing $27-2021,28-2020,\ldots,1023-1025$. So the only numbers remaining to be paired are $0,\ldots,26,1024$.

Now, we pair $0-1024,6-26,7-25,\ldots,15-17,3-5$. So all that is left is $1,2,4,16$. Pair $1-2,4-16$.

Now we are done, since at least one pair has $2$ elements inside the set. And, either the sum of those elements is a power of $2$, or one of the elements is a power of two, in which case the sum of it with itself is a power of $2$.

Comment: wow cool thank you so much :) i thought itt would be much more complicated :D

Comment: I think you have in fact shown that in fact any 1009-element subset $H$ already contains two elements that sum to a power of 2: you can merge the pairs (1,2) and (4,16), since if it contains any of the four elements (1,2,4,16) you already know it contains two elements that sum to a power of 2.

Comment: @BastiaanCnossen I agree. In fact, we can do even better by merging together all of the powers of $2$ into one bucket, and merging other buckets as well. But, there's no need to over-optimize, as this problem doesn't require it.